# How should this fraction involving powers be solved

Tags: exponentiation, fractions, square-numbers

> $$\sqrt { 5 } \cdot { \left( \frac { 5 }{ 4 }  \right)  }^{ \frac { 1 }{ 2 }  }$$

All I know is that this can be written as

$\sqrt { 5 } \cdot { \left( \frac { 5 }{ { 2 }^{ 2 } }  \right)  }^{ \frac { 1 }{ 2 }  }$

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

$$\sqrt { 5 } { \left( \frac { 5 }{ 4 }  \right)  }^{ \frac { 1 }{ 2 }  }={ 5 }^{ \frac { 1 }{ 2 }  }\cdot { \left( \frac { 5 }{ { 2 }^{ 2 } }  \right)  }^{ \frac { 1 }{ 2 }  }={ 5 }^{ \frac { 1 }{ 2 }  }\cdot \frac { { 5 }^{ \frac { 1 }{ 2 }  } }{ { \left( { 2 }^{ 2 } \right)  }^{ \frac { 1 }{ 2 }  } } =\frac { { 5 }^{ \frac { 1 }{ 2 } +\frac { 1 }{ 2 }  } }{ { 2 } } =\frac { 5 }{ 2 } $$

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt { 5 } { \left( \frac { \sqrt5 }{ \sqrt4 }  \right)}=$${\left( \frac { \sqrt {5*5} }{ 2 }  \right)}$=${\left( \frac { \sqrt {25} }{ 2 }  \right)}$=$\frac 52$